# I made a user input that takes integer, i want to print something if the input is string. How i do it?

Tags: python, input, integer

```
while True:
    age = int(input("*--How old are you?: "))

    if age < 18:
        print("Better go home!")
    elif age != int:
        print ("Use some numbers dude")
```

I tried some hours I searched but I don't understand it I just found the `.isdigit()`

Answer (score 0):

If the user inputs some non-digit string then the conversion to `int()` fails and `ValueError` is thrown.

You can handle this exception in `try...except` block. For example:

```py
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("*--How old are you?: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Use some numbers dude")
        continue

    if age < 18:
        print("Better go home!")
    else:
        print("OK")

    break
```

Prints:

```
*--How old are you?: twentyone
Use some numbers dude
*--How old are you?: 21
OK
```

Comment: Thank you, i havent learned the try and except !